# A word to describe someone doing things too quickly because they're in a rush and panicking

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> You look ___. No need to rush! It's 7.52 am!

I'm looking for a word that illustrate someone doing something but they are in rush.

> For example, I had told to be early in a meeting and I woke up late. I'm
> panic and afraid if my boss will lecture me again, so I put on my
> clothes and run to my office.  I don't even take a shower, don't eat,
> and have no time to comb my hair

My best thought is '**consternation**', because I realized that I woke up late and I only have 10 minutes before the meeting starts. However, I don't think it's a better word, though. I need a verb or an adjective, and if I'm in a condition that's described by this word, it's likely that I'm sweating, worried, and a bit dizzy.

It exists in my language, but I can't help to inform you this, because it's a kind of slang or word that you will never find on Google. It's a dialect and it doesn't even exist on my native language dictionary. Some native people in my country would possibly don't understand this word. Nevertheless, it's used in my town. I mention all of this because this situation can possibly be described by one word without telling what the word is that I have in my language.

Comment: Are you looking for a word to fill in that blank, or a word to describe someone doing something quick? I can't think of a word that does both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [**flustered**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flustered).

[For example:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Drunk_Driving_Defense/zTjcGQQtOGUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=flustered&pg=PA1006&printsec=frontcover)

> Q.  Would you characterize Mr. Kelly at the scene as being calm, cool, and collected?
> A.  Hardly.
> Q.  He was nervous, flustered?
> A.  I guess that would be pretty accurate.

*Consternation* is a state, so it doesn't exactly work in "Don't be ____."

Comment: But flustered doesn't mean doing something too quickly, which is what the OP asked for. I don't think there's an answer to this question.

Comment: @gotube I agree, but I don't think there's any one English word that captures that and "it's likely that I'm sweating, worried, and a bit dizzy".  We could just say "in a rush", or "in a hurry", but those don't capture the other aspects the OP is asking about.

Comment: Exactly a word that I want. Thank you so much. It answers my question by the way.

Comment: @gotube I'm sorry. Because of my lack of vocabulary, I couldn't describe it well. I do hope people will edit my post so that it looks neat and understandable, though.

Comment: @user516076 I'm happy you got the word you wanted! The other thing that confused me was, "Don't be ___." You cannot tell someone not to be flustered, just like you can't tell someone, "Don't be in pain!" They have no choice. So I've edited the title and the top of the question so maybe this question will be helpful to someone else some day

Comment: @gotube Why can't you tell someone "Don't be flustered"?  It simply means "in a state of agitated confusion", so you're just telling them to calm down and not get into such a state.  [Tom Lehrer used the very phrase in one of his songs.](https://genius.com/Tom-lehrer-be-prepared-lyrics)

Comment: @stangdon +1 and agreed that people certainly do say, "Don't be flustered". To me though, it doesn't make much more sense than "Don't be wet" or "Don't be exhausted", in the way people tell others what feelings not to have. The OP's clue "Don't be ____" was less helpful for answerers to imagine what word filled that blank than "You look ______".